# Unable to solve definite integral if an implicit function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, implicit-function

We were asked to find the area under the given function, as a challenging exercise:

\begin{gather*}
6x^{3} +11x^{2} y+6xy^{2} +y^{3} =x
\end{gather*}
The first thing I tried to do, was probably naive, and I immediately thought of finding the solution to y in terms of x as a cubic equation.

Needless to say, I really made a mess out of it.

Could someone please provide some hints on how to approach this kind of problem?
And it would also be helpful if anyone described a general method to deal with the area under an implicit function (if such a method exists).

Comment: $x = y^3 + 6xy^2 + 11x^2y + 6x^3 = (y + x)(y + 2x)(y + 3x)$  if that helps anyone

Comment: To compute the area **under** the function the limits of integration are needed. Besides the function seems to consist of three branches. Which one is in question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$6 x^3+11 x^2 y+6 x y^2+y^3=x$$
convert in polar coordinates
$$x=r\cos t;\;y=r\sin t$$
we get
$$r^3 \sin ^3 t+6 r^3 \cos ^3 t+11 r^3 \sin  t \cos ^2 t+6 r^3 \sin ^2 t \cos  t=r \cos  t$$
$r$ can be simplified and the equation can be solved wrt $r^2$
$$r^2 \sin ^3 t+6 r^2 \cos ^3 t+11 r^2 \sin  t \cos ^2 t+6 r^2 \sin ^2 t \cos  t- \cos  t=0$$
$$r^2=\frac{\cos  t}{\sin ^3 t+6 \cos ^3 t+11 \sin  t \cos ^2 t+6 \sin ^2 t \cos  t}$$
which can be simplified dividing numerator and denominator by $\cos^3 t$
$$r^2(t)=\frac{1}{\cos^2 t}\cdot \frac{1}{\tan^3 t+6\tan^2 t+11\tan t +6}$$
Any area $S$ we want to calculate can be solved by the integral
$$S=\frac12\int_a^b r^2(t) dt$$
Setting $\tan t=u$ we get
$$\int \frac{du}{u^3+6 u^2+11 u+6}=\int \left(-\frac{1}{u+2}+\frac{1}{2 (u+3)}+\frac{1}{2 (u+1)}\right)\,du=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2} \log (u+1)-\log (u+2)+\frac{1}{2} \log (u+3)+C=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\log \left(u^2+4 u+3\right)-2 \log(u+2)\right)+C=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{u^2+4 u+3}{(u+2)^2}\right)+C=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{\tan^2 t+4 \tan t+3}{(\tan t+2)^2}\right)$$
$$S=\left[\frac{1}{4}  \log \left(\frac{\tan^2 t+4 \tan t+3}{(\tan t+2)^2}\right)\right]_a^b$$
To get the area in the picture below we compute
$$S=\left[\frac{1}{4}  \log \left(\frac{\tan^2 t+4 \tan t+3}{(\tan t+2)^2}\right)\right]_0^{\pi/2}=\frac{1}{4} \log \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)\approx 0.072 $$

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you used polar coordinates to arrive at the answer? Also for my second question, can this method that you used be generalised to all such implicit functions>

Comment: @IshraaqParvez I worked in usual coordinates and realized that the cubic was not easily solvable. Tried polar and it worked, with a very nice integral. Not a special reason, tbh